# Assigning a dictionary as a class attribute

Tags: python, class, dictionary, attributes

I have a class `Itinerary` that has two attributes: `destinations` and `startTime`

There is an equal chance between two itineraries (`opt1` and `opt2`) for `destinations` which are both dictionaries with destinations as keys and day of visiting (0,1,...n) as values.

There is also an equal chance between `startTime` being `datetime(2020,1,1,12,0,0)` and `datetime(2020,1,1,9,0,0)`

Here is my code:

```
class Itinerary:
    def __init__(self, destinations, startTime):
        self.destinations = np.random.choice(list(destinations), p = list(destinations.values()))
        self.startTime = np.random.choice(list(startTime), p = list(startTime.values()))
                
destinations = { opt1 : 0.5, opt2 : 0.5 }

startTime = { datetime(2020,1,1,12,0,0) : 0.5, datetime(2020,1,1,9,0,0) : 0.5 }

d = Itinerary(destinations, startTime)
```

But I get the error: `TypeError: unhashable type 'dict'`

How can I assign a dictionary as a class attribute? I have the feeling it has something to do with `np.random.choice` in the function but I haven't figured it out.

Comment: What is `opt1` and `opt2` ?

Comment: @AndrejKesely the two itineraries that can be chosen. I have edited the post. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: You have initialized `destinations` and `startTime` as tuples. Also what is your intended data type for these 2 attributes. `dict` or `int`?

Comment: @MrSoLoDoLo the first attribute is a dictionary, for example:
`opt1 = {'a' : 0, 'b' : 1, 'c' : 2}`
`opt2 = {'a' : 0, 'b' : 1, 'c' : 2, 'd' : 3}`

and the second attribute is `datetime`:
`datetime(2020,1,1,12,0,0)` or `datetime(2020,1,1,9,0,0)`

Comment: @grimrol123 Ok my apologies. Your attributes were of `int` and not `tuple`. Is your goal here to access a random key from both dictionaries?

Comment: I am confused because you say you want random values but then you input the probabilities yourself when creating a new object.

Comment: @MrSoLoDoLo Yes, I probably should have explained why but I intend to add more dictionaries with assigned probabilities later on. You can see my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this. Thanks to everyone who helped.

```
class Itinerary:
    def __init__(self, destinations, startTime):
        self.destinations = np.random.choice((destinations), p = prob)
        self.startTime = np.random.choice(list(startTime), p = list(startTime.values()))
                
destinations = [ opt1, opt2 ]
prob = [ 0.5, 0.5 ]
startTime = { datetime(2020,1,1,12,0,0) : 0.5, datetime(2020,1,1,9,0,0) : 0.5 }

d = Itinerary(destinations, startTime)
```